# ngIf is not working in a JavaScript approach inside a Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this HTML inside of **my osmontagem.component.html**, this is the code :

```
<div class="card-filter">

              <h5 class="card-title-content">Opções</h5>
              <div class="row m--margin-bottom-20 card-content-custom">                  
                  <div class="btn-group mb-2 mr-2">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Opções</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu">
                          <a class="dropdown-item pointer" (click)="storeOsPimData()">Cadastrar <i class="feather icon-plus-circle"></i></a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item pointer" (click)="showViewOsData('S')">Editar</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item pointer" (click)="deleteOs()">Deletar</a>
                      </div>
                  </div> 
                  <div class="btn-group mb-2 mr-2">
                      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Ações</button>
                      <div class="dropdown-menu">
                          <a class="dropdown-item pointer" (click)="showViewOsData('N')">Visualizar <i class="feather icon-plus-circle"></i></a>
                          <ng-container *ngIf="this.tableName === 'iniTb'">
                            <a class="dropdown-item pointer" (click)="executeOs()">Executar</a> 
                          </ng-container>       
                          <ng-container *ngIf="this.tableName === 'execTb'">
                            <a class="dropdown-item pointer">Finalizar</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item pointer">Devolver</a> 
                          </ng-container>                      
                      </div>
                  </div>          
              </div>     
          </div>
```

Look my *ngIf it is working fine when I change the variable in an Angular way with this function

```
  public changeTbTemp(event) {
    const elementId: string = (event.target as Element).id;
    this.tableName = elementId;
  }
```

But I don't want that, I use a dataTable a jquery plugin inside my component and in the last line from the javascript function I use this :

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      if (e.target.id === 'iniTb') {
        tabletemp = iniTb;
      } else if (e.target.id === 'execTb') {
        tabletemp = execTb;
      } else if (e.target.id === 'finishTb') {
        tabletemp = finishTb;
      } else if (e.target.id === 'devoTb') {
        tabletemp = devTb;
      }
      changeTempTable(e.target.id, tabletemp);
    });

    const changeTempTable = (tablenamedata, tabletempdata) => {
      // this.tableName = tablenamedata;
      // this.tempTable = tabletempdata;
      this.changeTbTemp(tablenamedata, tabletempdata);
    };
```

If u see the function u will see that I get the ID from an element and change the options from a dropdown menu, I can't reference a global variable from typescript if i use function() from javascript so I use this:

```
const changeTempTable = (tablenamedata, tabletempdata) => {
      // this.tableName = tablenamedata;
      // this.tempTable = tabletempdata;
      this.changeTbTemp(tablenamedata, tabletempdata);
    };
```

Now I can have the variable or function from typescript file that is osmontagem.component.ts and is working fine, the variable is changing if you guys see in this picture from console :

Debug image

[image: Debug image]

But when I change this way is not working but if I use the Angular way is working, Why? I need to use javascript way because I have some variables inside that I want my typescript file see it.

Here is my second picture from my approach

[Second approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHuoD.png)

Comment: When you call the function, you are sending two args but the declaration has only one. Are you aware of this?

Comment: When using the angular way it is working because of the scope. When done using `jquery`, the context of `this` changes and so it doesn't work.

Comment: I know Sachin about this, because of that I use this function :  const changeTempTable = (tablenamedata, tabletempdata) => {
      // this.tableName = tablenamedata;
      // this.tempTable = tabletempdata;
      this.changeTbTemp(tablenamedata, tabletempdata);
    };

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working, i don't know why but this function from bootstrap

**$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.pill', (e) => {}**

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.pill', (e) => {
      if (e.target.id === 'iniTb') {
        tabletemp = iniTb;
      } else if (e.target.id === 'execTb') {
        tabletemp = execTb;
      } else if (e.target.id === 'finishTb') {
        tabletemp = finishTb;
      } else if (e.target.id === 'devoTb') {
        tabletemp = devTb;
      }
      this.tableName = 'execTb';
  });
```

is not working when you want to change a global variable from a component file, I just change the function to this a simple click event from jquery

```
$('.nav-link').click((e) => {
      if (e.target.id === 'iniTb') {
        tabletemp = iniTb;
      } else if (e.target.id === 'execTb') {
        tabletemp = execTb;
      } else if (e.target.id === 'finishTb') {
        tabletemp = finishTb;
      } else if (e.target.id === 'devoTb') {
        tabletemp = devTb;
      }
      this.tableName = e.target.id;
    });
```

now is working fine, I post this if anyone have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use arrow function `(e) => {}` in your jQuery callback instead of function. So the `this` context wont get changed. Change detection will happen in angular.

```
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', (e) => { 
if (e.target.id === 'iniTb') {
 tabletemp = iniTb;
 } else if (e.target.id === 'execTb') { 
tabletemp = execTb; 
} else if (e.target.id === 'finishTb') { 
tabletemp = finishTb; 
} else if (e.target.id === 'devoTb') { 
tabletemp = devTb; 
} 

this.changeTbTemp(e.target.id, tabletemp); });
```

You should also remove `this` in your *ngIf. The correct way is `*ngIf="tableName === 'iniTb'"`

Comment: I try your approach but is not working, I dunno why! The variable is changing the problem is that *ngIf is not working

Comment: You should also remove this in your *ngIf. The correct way is *ngIf="tableName === 'iniTb'"

Comment: Is not working too, if I remove the this, I think Angular does not work if is manipulation from DOM, I think *ngIf only work if an Angular event or function work in an Angular way, i will edit my question and put another picture see that